# Status{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null}

Tags: android, google-api

I'm trying to use Login with google feature in my app. I want to retrieve basic profile information.
I'm not finding any new tutorial for this purpose.Found this solution [Login with g+ on google developers site](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/)

this tutorial gives **GoogleSignInResult result** as **Status{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null}**
Can any one suggest step by step method to integrate g+ login in my app

Comment: This tutorial is best and update... Share your logout along with it so that I could help you

Comment: i followed tutorial still                 GoogleSignInResult result=Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data); ..result.toString() shows this status ...Status{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null}..pls help

Comment: Dear, i am asking for exceptions you might be having them in your logcat

Comment: There is no exception.but when i'm logging this result it' showing this status,pls give me step by step soln what needs to be done